# Getting a PMF for Linear Combination

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable

I am not sure how to get the PMF of a linear combination of two geometric variables

Question:

A university gives placement exams in math and verbal skills. To the nearest minute, the time it takes student to complete math exam has geometric distribution with parameter 0.02, and the time it takes a student to complete the verbal exam has a geometric distribution with parameter 0.025.

Determine the PMF of the total time that a student takes to complete both exams.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so the total time in minutes for a student taking both exams will be the sum of the two times each being geometric with slightly different parameters.

Comment: Linear combinations of discrete variables are in general a little tricky, but this is a plain sum of independent r.v.s on the integers which makes life considerably easier. It's a straight convolution: $P(Z =z)   =P(X+Y=z)$ $=\Sigma_yP(X=z−y,Y=y)$ $=
\Sigma_y P(X=z−y|Y=y)P(Y=y)$ $
=\Sigma_y P(X=z−y)P(Y=y)$ .... This looks like it's amenable to straightforward algebraic manipulation on your problem

Comment: Since this is `self-study` please add the tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question as needed (in short, we're not going to just be doing the exercise for you; if you make a proper attempt we may be able to help guide you). See the help on [how to ask a good question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in relation to search and research, and the help on what's [on topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in relation to homework and related kinds of questions